# Lightning formatted number not working for LWR site

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud, lwr, lightning-formatted-number

I have lwc component and I'm using **lightning-formatted-number** with currency type as Euro. In SF documentation -

"The locale set in your Salesforce user settings determines where to display spaces, commas, and periods in numbers, and the currency used by default"[Reference link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-number/documentation).

As per my requirement, locale is German and I have to use this in **LWR site** and I'm logging as authenticated user (not as guest user).

```
<lightning-formatted-number value="123455" format-style="currency">
```

I'm getting result as €123,455.00 instead of €123.455,00.
Euro symbol is coming as per the locale set but commas, and periods in the currency are not coming as per German currency format. Is this a bug in LWR?